# What is wrong with this Numpy/Pandas code to construct new boolean column based on the values in two other boolean columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data set:

Beginning Data Set:

```
ObjectID,Date,Price,Vol,Mx
101,2017-01-01,,145,203
101,2017-01-02,,155,163
101,2017-01-03,67.0,140,234
101,2017-01-04,78.0,130,182
101,2017-01-05,58.0,178,202
101,2017-01-06,53.0,134,204
101,2017-01-07,52.0,134,183
101,2017-01-08,62.0,148,176
101,2017-01-09,42.0,152,193
101,2017-01-10,80.0,137,150
```

I first create two new columns of boolean values called VolPrice and Check based on the values in my starting data set. I think want to create a third additional column called DoubleCheck where the value of this column should be True if either VolPrice OR Check are equal to True, otherwise the value of DoubleCheck should be false. Initially I got the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

but then I added .any() after each column within my statement to construct the DoubleCheck column. However this isn't working either because it is providing 'True' values throughout the DoubleCheck column even when there should be false values as shown below.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Observations = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Observations.csv", parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['ObjectID', 'Date'])

Observations['VolPrice'] = np.where((Observations['Price']<Observations['Vol']) & (Observations['Vol']<Observations['Mx']), True, False)
Observations['Check'] = np.where(Observations['Vol']<Observations['Price'], True, False)
Observations['DoubleCheck'] = np.where((Observations['Check'].any()==True) or (Observations['VolPrice'].any()==True), True, False)

print(Observations)
```

Current Result:

```
ObjectID,Date,Price,Vol,Mx,VolPrice,Check,DoubleCheck
101,2017-01-01,,145,203,False,False,True
101,2017-01-02,,155,163,False,False,True
101,2017-01-03,67.0,140,234,True,False,True
101,2017-01-04,78.0,130,182,True,False,True
101,2017-01-05,58.0,178,202,True,False,True
101,2017-01-06,53.0,134,204,True,False,True
101,2017-01-07,52.0,134,183,True,False,True
101,2017-01-08,62.0,148,176,True,False,True
101,2017-01-09,42.0,152,193,True,False,True
101,2017-01-10,80.0,137,150,True,False,True
```

Desired Result:

```
ObjectID,Date,Price,Vol,Mx,VolPrice,Check,DoubleCheck
101,2017-01-01,,145,203,False,False,False
101,2017-01-02,,155,163,False,False,False
101,2017-01-03,67.0,140,234,True,False,True
101,2017-01-04,78.0,130,182,True,False,True
101,2017-01-05,58.0,178,202,True,False,True
101,2017-01-06,53.0,134,204,True,False,True
101,2017-01-07,52.0,134,183,True,False,True
101,2017-01-08,62.0,148,176,True,False,True
101,2017-01-09,42.0,152,193,True,False,True
101,2017-01-10,80.0,137,150,True,False,True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `|` for bitwise `OR`, working same like `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
Observations['DoubleCheck'] = Observations['Check'] | Observations['VolPrice']
```

Or [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with both columns:

```
Observations['DoubleCheck'] = Observations[['Check','VolPrice']].any(axis=1)
```

All together is possible without `np.where`:

```
Observations['VolPrice'] = (Observations['Price']<Observations['Vol']) & (Observations['Vol']<Observations['Mx'])
Observations['Check'] = Observations['Vol']<Observations['Price']
Observations['DoubleCheck'] = Observations['Check'] | Observations['VolPrice']
```